# CPU Usage Gadget doesn't stay "always on top"

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

This seems very trivial, but for the past 3 years I have not found a solution. I have the cpu gadget on the side bar. I have it checked to be "always on top". However after a while, seemingly randomly, it will just not be on top. I have to click show desktop then click on the gadget once and it will be on top again. Although it is trivial, its been bugging me for the past 3 years. Is there any solution to this or is this just a bug.

Note: I also have the gadget set to opacity 60.

Comment: This only happens with certain windows.  Sounds like you have software that attempt to override the "always on top" by trying to "always be on top: themselfs.

Comment: I have a similar issue here with windows 7 64. Different windows will act up, not come foreward correctally, or end up over a program that was set to always on top.  It is very random. After a reboot they will work fine for quite some time.  I dont reboot for weeks, so i have learned to live with it.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/3ca02a30-6e0d-4d2a-81f7-a4c8fd28fcff/ <-- I was hoping that there were other people who noticed it. I wonder if it ever gets seen on 32bit only type of systems.

Comment: @Ramhound Even if i have windows that attempt to override the "always on top", after I close those, shouldnt the gadget still stay on top of the normal windows?...it doesnt in my case.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who wants to know, the gadget not staying on top, this worked for me, however involved registry add/and/or tweak ; always back up before doing anything in registry first, if not comfortable don't do this ;

Navigate to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Sidebar\Settings Create a new DWORD Value called AllowElevatedProcess Set the value of the new DWORD to 1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Sidebar\Settings Create a new DWORD Value called AllowElevatedProcess Set the value of the new DWORD to 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Sidebar\Compatibility Create a new DWORD Value called AllowElevatedProcess Set the value of the new DWORD to 1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\IEOverride\Settings Create a new DWORD Value called AllowElevatedProcess Set the value of the new DWORD to 1

If the value Settings and/or Compatibility are not there you'll have to make that key i.e. new key.

Don't attempt this if you're not familiar with registry though.

Next Start Task Manager; click Show processes from all users; find sidebar.exe; right click; find Set Priority; reset to High; close Task Manager.

Reboot computer afterward.